# Boolean array comparisons Java

Tags: java

I have made a class called `Iset` that takes integers and modifies it's boolean array's index equivalent to the integer to true.

e.g. If I pass an integer 1 then the boolean array `setI[1]` is turned to true.

I have a method called `include` that returns true if the provided integer is in there and false if it isn't. However no matter what I do I always get `true`. I have made sure that everything in the array is set to false and I add in a number further up the code. Obviously I'm missing something really obvious here:

```
public class Iset {
    public int size;
    boolean[] setI;

    Iset(int a) {
        this.size = a;
        this.setI = new boolean[size];
    }

    public boolean include(int i) {
        for (int n = 0; n <= size; n++) {
            if (setI[n]== setI[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `setI`? What is `size`? Show us the code that fills `setI`.

Comment: `takes integers and stores them in a boolean array` you should rethink this. What is about an int array ?

Comment: why are you storing integers in a `boolean` array? And how exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @Rohit I made the edit... It was slightly wrong to state "storing integers in boolean array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to walk over the complete array, just ask the method if your number is included.

```
public boolean isIncluded(int i) {
    if (setI[i] == true){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or even simpler:

```
public boolean isIncluded(int i) {
    return setI[i];
}
```

P.S. I changed your method name to something more meaningful

Comment: `contains` might be even better, since that's what's used in the Collections APIs.

Comment: in general yes, but we do not know what the context is, it may be that "isIncluded" makes more sense ;)

Comment: That's a very straight forward way of doing it. Problem is when I think too hard at something I just end up making it more and more complicated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have given solutions, but I think we can also get an explanation going as to why your original code was slightly wrong as you say. Here is what your include() method is doing in pseudocode:

```
for each boolean called 'setI[n]' in the array:
    if 'setI[n]' is the same as the boolean at 'setI[i]':
        return true
```

So, it's not actually checking if either of those boolean are true or false, it's just checking if they are the same. This method will always return true *unless* the boolean at index `i` is the only one in the array with its value (I'd suggest trying that to see if I am right). For example, if `i = 1` your method will return `true` for:

```
[false, true, false, false, ...]
[true, false, true, true, ...]
```

... and no other values.

Hopefully this makes things a little clearer.

Comment: Thank you for reinforcing the ideas laid out. Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code, I think you should add a funktion: set(), and change a little of the include(int i)

```
public class Iset {
public int size;
boolean[] setI;

Iset(int a) {
    this.size = a;
    this.setI = new boolean[size];
}

public boolean include(int i) {

    return setI[i];
}

    //set your values in the boolean array "setI" to "true" 

public void set(int... values) {

    for (int i : values) {
        setI[i] = true;

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Iset mm = new Iset(100);

    mm.set(25, 40, 22);

    System.out.println(mm.include(25));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean include(int i) {
    if (i >= size){
        // To avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        return false;
    }
    return setI[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are after for, but, in you for-loop you are making a selfcomparison when `n == i` and thus return true always.